# Dependencies between BuildConfigurations in TeamCity when deploying

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, teamcity, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to correctly deploy to different environments with TeamCity (in terms of cross BuildConfiguration dependencies) and hope to get some input as to how to configure my SubProjects/BuildConfigurations properly. Lets start based on a concrete example: I made this test "TeamcityConfigurationTests" to better learn how TeamCity handled dependencies, and the current state shows the result i am looking for:

[image]

I have 3 subProjects, Dev, Test and Prod - and all associated tasks for those "environments" as seperate build configurations within that subProject. This is to more clearly visualize what is going on, and if anything breaks, to be able to see immediately what is broken (separate Build, UnitTest and DeployToDev BuildConfigurations, rather than 3 different steps in one single Build Configuration).

Ideally, i only want to build my application **once** in the **Dev.Build** step, and let the **Dev.UnitTest** and **Dev.DeployToDev** steps grab that artifact and run tests and deploy. That i got going for me, by having snapshot and artifact dependencies. But i am having trouble getting the correct artifact when i want to deploy from **Dev -> Test** or **Test -> Prod**.

My issue is to correctly reference the latest successfully DEV deployed artifact when running **Test.DeployToTest** - and the same for getting the latest successfully TEST deployed artifact when running **Prod.DeployToProd**. (Essentially i want to promote the artifact to the next environment).

Now, my issue is, if I in the **Test.DeployToTest** have a SnapshotDependency to **Dev.DeployToDev** and an artifact dependency to **Dev.Build**, and the VCS source has changed since Deploy to Dev has run, it triggeres running all the DEV steps again. This is not the worst part, the same happens when i run **Prod.DeployToProd** if the VCS source changed since the initial build on dev (because of all the snapshot dependencies). Meaning, that rather than promoting **Test -> Prod**, I Build and deploy whatever is currently on VCS to Dev, Test AND Prod.

How am i supposed to set this up correctly?

The only other option i am aware of, is letting **Dev.DeployToDev** also publish the same artifact, and only have an (LatestSuccessful) ArtifactDependency in **Test.DeployToTest**. I would also have to publish the artifact again in **Test.DeployToTest**, for letting **Prod.DeployToProd** only have a (LatestSuccessfull) artifact dependency to **Test.DeployToTest**. (This would be to get rid of the SnapshotDependencies causing previous environments to run build/deploy again in case of VCS changes). But then i am publishing the artifact 3 times, rather than just the one time when the application is originally built in DEV - which i would like to avoid. Also, i have cases where no artifact is needed for deploying to Test and Prod, so there is no artifact to depend on (essentially i only need the BuildNumber from the "Dependent" environment i want to promote from).

I hope for some input. Thank you

Regards

Frederik

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, i made a JetBrains support ticket, and got the following response:

> Basically, there are options to resolve your case:
>
> Option 1: use "Promote" action form the build's Actions top-right menu
>   (or change the type of the Deploy* configurations to deployment and
>   use the action from the block on the build results. This is the
>   preferred way: before deploying you select the build to deploy and
>   "promote" it to the next environment. There is also an experimental
>   hidden feature to hide the "Run" button: add
>   "teamcity.ui.runButton.caption" configuration parameter in the build
>   configurations to empty value.
>
> Option 2: do not use snapshot dependency, use only artifact dependency
>   on the latest successful build. However, when you run the build you
>   cannot be sure that the last successful build you see will be
>   deployed: while the build is standing int he queue, another
>   Dev.DeployToDev can finish and then be deployed as the last
>   successful.

**We went with option 1**